# Get Client system's directory/folder list using client script HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, windows

Related to this topic I know that impossible to get local computer folder list from webpage.
https://forums.asp.net/t/1326036.aspx?Get+Client+system+s+directory+folder+list+using+client+script
But how about if I open a html file on my own computer, it will be any way to do it?
Or i need to create .exe which will display my html and include some function to read files on computer...
Thank for any sugesstions.

Comment: Not possible in any way. It would be a ***massive*** security flaw if it was

Comment: Probably you're searching something like https://electron.atom.io/

Comment: @dloeda Thank you. I'm interested in your solution :)